# ioctl problem with partition

Tags: linux, block-device, api

There is a path to the file, I make a write disk cache request via ioctl - `ioctl(fd, SG_IO, &ioHdr)`.

printk: sending ioctl 2285 to a partition!? how to find out which block device a partition belongs to ? I want to replace partition path with path to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, who says a partition belongs to a single block device? Often, it's something stretched across multiple disks using some sort of device manager, e.g. mdraid, lvm.

Anyways, if it is on a single block device:

You read `/sys/block/nvme0n1/dev`; this will give you a `major:minor` kind of information. Your "mother device" is then `major:0`; you can thus read `/sys/dev/block/${major}:0/device` to get the "canonical name" of the device.

**If** (and that's a strong if!) there's an entry in /dev, it's the one with the major,minor as `${major},0`.